# How to change the color of bootstrap borders (not table borders)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, border

Trying to change the border colour of a div element with the class `.border`, how do you change the colour of this to a non-bootstrap specified color in css, i.e

```
.border{
   color: #E9C8FF;
}
```

Comment: You need to make your selector more specific than Bootstrap's, or as specific and load it after Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: As explaned in the dup, you'll need to use `!important` to override Bootstrap, because the Utility classes use `!important`.